# ReactNative componentDidMount doesn't get called

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two screens: A and B, connected with a StackNavigator

Screen A is a QR code scanner. As soon as a QR code is scanned, it navigates to screen B.

In screen B, I make an API call using the QR code that gets passed as a navigation param from screen A. I trigger this API call in componentDidMount.

My issue is: if I navigate from A to B, then back to A, then to B again, componentDidMount does not get called and I have no way to trigger the API call.

---

## EDIT:

Here's some code

**Screen A**

Handler function that gets called when a QR code is scanned:

```
handleQRCode = qrCode => {
    NavigationService.navigate('Decode', {qrCode});
};
```

**Screen B**

The QR code is pulled from the navigation state params and used for an API call (startDecode) through redux.

```
componentDidMount() {
    qrCode = this.props.navigation.state.params.qrCode;
    this.props.startDecode(qrCode.data);
}
```

My issue is that componentDidMount only gets called the first time that route is taken.

Comment: Can you share a piece of code?

Comment: @JoseVf I just added some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-navigation` each screen is kept mounted. This means that when you you go back to B, you might have changed the props, but `componentDidMount` was already invoked in the first creation of this screen.

There are two options available for you (AFAIK) that can handle this case:

1. Instead of calling `this.props.navigation.navigate()` you can use
   `this.props.navigation.push` which will create another instance of
   screen B, thus invoking the `componentDidMount` React lifecycle
   event.
2. In screen B you can catch the event where its props have changed.
   This can take place in the new static lifecycle event
   `getDerivedPropsFromState` or it can be done in the soon to be
   deprecated `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: I tried push like this -> this.props.navigation.push('Decode', {qrCode}) but componentDidMount still doesn't get called.

Comment: I also don't necessarily change the props when I go to screen B, but I expect it to trigger the API call again to refresh the local copy

Comment: regarding your first reply - that's truly weird because by definition `push` should create a new instance, thus calling `componentDidMount`

Comment: regarding your second reply - If you're not changing the props than you're just showing the already mounted screen B, so `componentDidMount` will not be called again

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue and I used `this.props.navigation.addListener()` to resolve it. Basically, force-calling `componentDidMount()` may be possible by pushing same screen again [using a key](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens) (I haven't tried it) but your stack will keep growing as well, which is not optimal. So, when you return to a screen already in stack, you can use `addListener()` to see if it is being re-focused, and you can replicate you `componentDidMount()` code here:

```
class MyClass extends Component {

  someProcess = () => {
    // Code common between componentDidMount() and willFocus()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.someProcess();
  }

  willFocus = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    (payload) => {
      this.someProcess();
    }
  );

}
```

When `MyClass` is called for the first time, `componentDidMount` will get called. For the other times when it is still in stack but instead just gains focus, `addListener` will get called.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the B component is mounted only on the first time it is accessed, so componentDidMount won't be called again.

I recommend you to pass a callback to the `setOnNavigatorEvent` method of your navigator, with the 'didAppear' event. Your callback will be invoked on every event emitted by react-native-navigation, and you can verify to do your logic every time the screen appears (hence the use of 'didAppear' event). You can base your code on the following:

```
export default class ExampleScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
  }

  onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    if (event.id === 'didAppear') {
      // do API call here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but is this wix's version of react navigation? I can't call setOnNavigatorEvent on my stack navigator

Comment: Yes, it is. Check the documentation https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=setonnavigatoreventcallback

Comment: What happens when you try to use it?

Comment: "not a function". I'm using https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html

Comment: That's not from wix. By the tag 'react-native-navigation' on your post I thought you were using wix's.

Comment: My apologies, I should've paid attention to the tags. I updated them.